# How to find with grep lines that end in a certain string?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I know that to find a REGEX that ends in a certain string I have to write `"string$"`. Although I tried the following variations of grep : `cat foo | grep "string$"`, `cat foo | egrep "string$", grep -E "string$", grep "string\$"` I did not get any found lines although such line exists.

Comment: Please give example of such line which doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put an example of such lines and the full command you have used?

Comment: I verbatim typed in my shell: cat soi | grep "ing$"  (and the variations of it)

Comment: Do those files have dos style line endings ?

Comment: I do not know what dos style line endings are , but for instance cat soi | grep "^I"  works.

Comment: They are a carriage return and a line feed instead of just a line feed. If thats the case, `file <your_file>` should tell you "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators".

Comment: I get this massage: soi: HTML document, ASCII text

Comment: What do you see in the output of `sed -n '/string/l'`?

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
grep 'ing$' soi
```

`cat`is not needed. Try with single quotes.

Single quotes prevent the shell from interpreting `$` as the beginning of a variable name.

Comment: Why the backslash?

Comment: An error. Corrected. You could need the backslash if you are looking for  for lines that end in `.ing`, so the backslash escapes the dot.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to make the `$` work as end-of-line.

If you want to `grep` with some variable also, use both double and single quotes as below:

```
grep -- "$var"'$'
```